# What are the rationales for token in js-based APIs

Tags: javascript, api, token

A lot of "javascript API" such as the ones available from google for tracking, etc... provide you with a token to initialize the API. What are the rationales for such a design ? Is it to simplify tracking on the backend side for the service which provides such APIs ? The idea "sounds" natural to me, but being relatively new to web development, I don't think I really understand the implication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracking and control. They can make sure you are only using it on registered domains and if usage stops conforming to their constraints they know who to contact and/or shutdown.